# problem with loading a file into a function

Tags: function, path

i'am trying to make a function that does the following
[image]

here is my code

```
def dataLoad(filename):
    import numpy as np
    import os #import operation system
    cwd=os.getcwd() #current working directory
    cwd
    os.path.abspath(filename)
    fin=open(filename,'r')
    BacteriaList={1:"Salmonella enterica",2:"Salmonella enterica",3:
                  "Listeria",4:" Brochothrix thermosphacta"}
    Data=fin
    #make an if statement inside a loop running through the Nx3 matrix 
    n=0
    for lines in range(len(Data)):
        while n<=(len(Data)):
           if 60<Data[1+n:1]<10:
                n=n+1
                print("invalid temperature in line {0}".format(n),)
                return(Data-Data[1+n:1],Data-Data[1+n:2],Data-Data[1+n:3])
           else:
               print(Data)
                
            
    #if any of these condition are not True:
        #Temperature : must be between 10-60:
            #if not then print "invalid temperature in line N"
            #Then proceed to the next
        #growth rate must be positive:
            #if not then print"growth rate can't be negative"
            #then proceeed
        #Bacteria within the four specified values:
            #if not then print "invalid bacteria"
        
        #proceed to the next line 
    #print only the lines that met these conditions
```

and the test file i want to open in the function is

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[10,30,20],[20,30,20],[65,45,12]])
```

however i get this error

```
object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

i'am not even sure if i understand the assigment correctly, if i misunderstood it please i would be greatfull if you could be kind to explain it. and please don't solve my entire assigment or else i won't learn! thank you